# Implement `Goto anything` search in mysql and/or nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js

Features like Sublime `Goto anything`, Jetbrains IDEs `Search everyhwhere` show a progressive search functionality that break words into letters and find all possible matches progressively.

In mysql such search could be implemented:

```
LIKE %word%                (High)
LIKE %wor%d% OR %w%ord%    (Medium)
LIKE %wo%rd% OR %w%or%d%   (Lower)
LIKE %w%o%r%d%             (Lowest)
```

This still needs union and distinct or alternately perform these steps on server side using node/php/etc.

Keen to know if there are ready made solutions out there or in mysql itself to achieve the same result as `Goto anything`.